# How can we calculate the total time to run the Orchestration function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am having an orchestration function which is managing some activities. I have a stopwatch to calculate the time taken to complete those activities. While running its reset the timer as the orchestration trigger keeps on replaying. Is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the history table of the durable Function and see the different timestamps for every step in the execution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-checkpointing-and-replay

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints#using-deterministic-apis) also describes why you should not use things like Stopwatch in a durable Function.

Answer (score -2):

You should not use Stopwatch in Orchestrator function. If you want Start and complete time of your orchestrator function, you can directly check in "DurableFunctionHubInstance" table (Function Storage account).

[image]